# d3 not appending/updating points to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, updates, geojson

I'm attempting to get a FeatureCollection GeoJSON of point data to append to a leaflet map using D3 v4. Here's a jsfilddle with the relevant code:
https://jsfiddle.net/op103ufm/

I have two major problems:

1. The data is not appending at all (only a g element is created in the DOM).
2. At some point I got data to append, but when zooming into the map, the circles got clipped off. As I understand this is because I am not getting the bounds on zooming, but I have also been unable to fix this issue. In fact, as you can see I'm getting bounds with leaflet methods because using the d3 method returned `Infinty` for the bounds.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed would be super appreciated!

Thanks so much.

Also, this is a structure of the parsed GeoJSON (I had to convert from a regular CSV).[image: geJSON]

Comment: Check this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/749df041c1945aef78fd992c7dfbe0e1) which is very easy to follow and maybe you can clear a bit your doubts.


Also, since you're creating your geojson from a csv file, validate it first with [JOSNLint](https://jsonlint.com/) so you can discard a bad formatted json as the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found that same example shortly after and I think it's the best. I was able to successfully plot my points. However, I'm dumbfounded now because that example does not use map.getBounds() or the d3 bounds method, so I don't understand how it works. Does it simply redraw everything on "moveend"? Isn't that super inefficient though?

Comment: Glad you managed to solve your problem. I don't really know how can you measure how inefficient this method is, but I guess translation of any SVG element involves rerendering the objects, so we'd be talking about the "same" or at least similar computational efforts. On the other hand, it seems that @mbostock also uses this method as you can see [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/), so it's probably a good practice. Hope this article helps you also with your questions.